# Python: Created custom package; error: name 'requests' is not defined (Although imported)

Tags: python, import, package

I tried to create my own python package (basically as described in the first 2 chapters of https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/developing-python-packages).

The folder structure of the package is like this:

mainfolder contains
a)setup.py
b)subfolder with the same name as mainfolder

subfolder contains
a)**init**.py (plus the 2 underscores in front and after init; somehow that is not shown here)
b) module1.py
c) module2.py
d) module3.py
e) module4.py

the only content of **init**.py is the import statement of all 4 modules.
I installed this package with "pip install -e setup.py".

I can successfully import either the whole package or single modules.
Sadly I have one problem I can't solve:
One of the module contains code for a function that uses requests.get() and .json() to extract data from an online API and extracts the json.

When i try to use this function in another code file (after importing the function of course) i get an error: name 'requests' is not defined.
And that is although I imported requests at the start of the code. I also can use requests normally without errors there. Only when using my custom function this error is raised.
I was only able to fix the error by rating the import requests statement INSIDE the custom function module, but that is not nice.
Somehow other packages like pandas or json work inside my custom package without importing it there.

Any ideas?
Sorry for my confusing trains of thoughts ;-)

Comment: I would give this question a bit of a rewrite so a reader can more quickly focus on what the problem is. It looks like you should use "error: name 'requests' is not defined." as a title. (Just my opinion and I could be way wrong).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the title a bit